# Can I use auto-renewing subscriptions without delivering content?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Can I do the auto renewable subscription to Apple without issuing any content? That is, the subscription to use certain features on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Apple App Store Review Guidelines:

> Apps may only use auto-renewing subscriptions for periodicals
>   (newspapers, magazines), business Apps (enterprise, productivity,
>   professional creative, cloud storage), and media Apps (video, audio,
>   voice), or the App will be rejected

Does your App fall into one of those categories? If yes, then you can use auto-renewing subscriptions.